# What is Silver The Hedgehog's full timeline?

Tags: time-travel, sonic-the-hedgehog

Silver The Hedgehog has a rough and bumpy timeline that I don't know where to start at, in 06 he was first introduced, but apparently when they destroyed Solaris it didn't fix his future, and I know that in the DS version of Sonic Colours (which actually would be more canon than the wii version) he states that his future is fixed. There is obviously a gap in between where at some point they fixed the future.